# Why centering children of "ion-content" doesn't work but centering children of a "div" does?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to center children of `ion-content` using this `HTML` and `SCSS` codes:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      GreenWalls application
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="center">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      Awesome content
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>

ion-card {
  max-width: 350px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But this approach doesn't result in centered content:

[image]

When I wrap the `ion-card` in `div` element and use the SCSS on the div element suddenly it works:

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="center">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-content>
        Awesome content
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

I don't wanna wrap content of each `ion-content` in `div` tags. Why the `SCSS` doesn't apply to the `ion-content`? How can I make it work in Ionic 4?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `<ion-grid>` to wrap the children of `<ion-content>` instead of `<div>` element.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid class="center">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-content>
        Awesome content
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ceq6a6)

---

### References

[Center grid in ion-content](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/center-grid-in-ion-content/160335)